# Finding roots of a non linear expression when multiplied with a linear expression

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a simple polynomial equation:

```
b^2 + 2b + 1 = 0
```

I could easily solve this as:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

eq = lambda b : np.power(b,2) + 2*b + 1
fsolve(eq, np.linspace(0,1,2))
```

Similarly I could solve any equation, that has finite number of terms. But how do I solve an equation with infinite number of terms which is given as :

[image]

The above equation could be written as :

```
5 = (1 - l) * (5.5 + 4.0*l + 4*l^2 + 6*l^3 + 5*l^4 + 5*l^5 + 5*l^6 + 5*l^7 + 5*l^8 + 5*l^9 + 5*l^10   )
```

when n goes from 1 to 10. But I want to solve this for sufficiently large value of `n` such that LHS ~= RHS.

I know the values of LHS and `G1 -> Ginf` but cannot understand how could I compute the value of lambda here.

I tried looking at [numpy polynomial functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) but could not find a function that is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

The following glosses over the fact that I do not 100% understand the coefficient notation `G_t:t+n` (what kind of dependency is that supposed to indicate exactly?)

Obviously, the solution will depend on coefficients. If as your example suggests, the coefficients are all equal above some index `n_0` then your r.h.s. expression is a telescoping sum and equal to `G_t:1` + sum_1^n_0 [G_t:n - G_t:n+1] l^n`. Be sure to note that this sum is finite, so you know how to proceed from here.

One caveat: you must have `|l| < 1` otherwise the series does not converge and the r.h.s. is undefined, although some kind of continuation argument may be possible.